# Functions pulling from a refreshing power query giving REF! error

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a changing power query which size changes based on the amount of PDF's from a folder. I have functions set up on a separate sheet tab to pull data from a range of cells from the power query tab. The main problem I have is if I load only a few of these pdf's my references will get deleted since the table range is getting removed. I have been trying to find work arounds to this, any help would be appreciated.

I tried to do a Pivot table of this data I need but I am trying to match certain criteria like an invoice and specific words to get a value. This did not work for my situation.

[Example of Power Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMaHv.png)

[this is the data I am pulling that will turn into REF! if I take a pdf out and the rows shrink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojlRX.png)

Comment: Off-topic but why are you using OFFSET with INDEX? Why not something like: `=INDEX(Query!$D2:$F7,MATCH($D$1,Query!$D2:$F7),2)`

Comment: I need to use offset cause its more accurate for me since I am trying to find my match and there's a possibility it wont be in the same spot vertically, but having the offset i can guarantee I will get the correct value and move two right. This was just kind of a basic version of my actual file. there's typically a lot of data within D:D. I tried plugging in that formula too and was getting an N/A.

Comment: Why aren't you routing the results of the powerquery into a table? If that is your powerquery output, why are you not changing it into a more normalized format without blank rows?

Comment: But the second condition of INDEX set to 2 offsets 2 columns from the first indexed column already (have you tried my example?). Offset will keep on recalculating at any change in the file, therefore I suggest avoiding it.